# why my div image not float left

Tags: html, css

I need all images div to float `left`.
Have a look at my [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4SUV.jpg), how can I remove that free space.

This is my `html` code:

```
<div class="book_items row">
    <div class="book1"><img src="images/book1.jpg" style="width: 80%;"></div>
    <div class="book1"><img src="images/book2.jpg" style="width: 80%;"></div>
    <div class="book1"><img src="images/book3.jpg" style="width: 80%;"></div>
    <div class="book1"><img src="images/book4.jpg" style="width: 80%;"></div>
    <div class="book1"><img src="images/book5.jpg" style="width: 80%;"></div>
    <div class="book1"><img src="images/book6.jpg" style="width: 80%;"></div>
    <div class="book1"><img src="images/book7.jpg" style="width: 80%;"></div>
    <div class="book1"><img src="images/book8.jpg" style="width: 80%;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.book1{
    width: 22%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;    
}
```

Comment: https://s30.postimg.org/92an2r0i9/sus.jpg

Comment: You need to make your question clear. Do you want to remove the spaces between the images? if so remove the `margin-left` from `.book1`. If its the space under, you can put the `height` of your `parent div` to `auto` so it only expands to the height of its `child`

Comment: i mean , want my image order like this https://s29.postimg.org/4gm3vp0ef/sus2.jpg   but when i change resolution for responsive always have big free space between some image https://s29.postimg.org/dzhywrhnr/sus3.jpg

Comment: you want thesame order on screen resize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your images: they are not all identical size. you can edit them to have identical aspect ratio or you can specify the height for the divs containing them .

Here's an example:

```css
.book1{
width: 22%;
text-align: center;
height: 160px;
margin-top: 25px;
margin-left: 15px;
float: left; 
overflow:hidden;
}
body,html{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.book_items{
width:100%;
margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="book_items row">
<div class="book1"><img src="http://img.phombo.com/img1/photocombo/15189/Top_100_Wallpapers_360_X_640_by-85.jpg_Nature_Butterfly.jpg" style="width: 80%;"></div>
<div class="book1"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/Attenborough_Nature_Reserve_-_geograph.org.uk_-_202642.jpg/240px-Attenborough_Nature_Reserve_-_geograph.org.uk_-_202642.jpg" style="width: 80%;"></div>
<div class="book1"><img src="http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w/images/thumb/3/3c/Salto_del_Angel-Canaima-Venezuela08.JPG/240px-Salto_del_Angel-Canaima-Venezuela08.JPG" style="width: 80%;"></div>
<div class="book1"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/Attenborough_Nature_Reserve_-_geograph.org.uk_-_202642.jpg/240px-Attenborough_Nature_Reserve_-_geograph.org.uk_-_202642.jpg" style="width: 80%;"></div>
<div class="book1"><img src="http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w/images/thumb/3/3c/Salto_del_Angel-Canaima-Venezuela08.JPG/240px-Salto_del_Angel-Canaima-Venezuela08.JPG" style="width: 80%;"></div>
<div class="book1"><img src="http://picsmobi.net/uploads/pictures/nature-pictures/64233-beautiful-nature.jpg" style="width: 80%;"></div>
<div class="book1"><img src="http://www.rspb.org.uk/groups/images/loughborough_25032011181306_352.jpg" style="width: 80%;"></div>
</div>
```